# "Attitude should be professional looks need not to be" is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tenses

Is this sentence is wrong?

> Attitude should be professional looks need not to be

If yes, then what's the correct way or approach to write it in a correct grammatical way?

May I know why it should be "needs" instead of "need", and "look" instead of "looks" as suggested by some?

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more.  It is not grammatically correct.

Comment: You must insert a comma after 'professional' and 'look' should be singular : "*Attitude should be professional, look needs not to be*”

Comment: @Rayner what's the correct grammatical way to say same thing?

Comment: Are you trying to say, "One should always have a professional attitude, regardless of the way they look" - ?

Comment: @Graffito thank you for help but may i know why you used "needs" instead of "need" and "look" instead of  "looks" ?

Comment: @Rayner yes exactly but the sentenced i made to say it can i use it in talking with someone or its wrong it require some changes ?

Comment: Using "look" or "looks" is a matter of opinion. In my first, I should not have used the verb "should". Usage is perhaps different according to countries (UK, US, ...).

Comment: Maybe this is better:  "You should always have a professional attitude, no matter what you look like."

Comment: You can rephrase it as follows: Attitude should be professional, while looks do not need to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Or just: Attitude should be professional, looks need not be.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Why is this helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The only *grammatical* correction I would make would be to delete *to,* but the sentence does need punctuation after *professional.* Semicolon or em dash is probably your best bet there. As for *look* vs. *looks,* I would positively prefer the former, singular form, even though the plural form might be more familiar: one’s *looks* refers more to the gifts of nature (high cheekbones, straight nose, that sort of thing), where one’s *look* refers more to an ensemble of clothing and accessories, with coiffure and grooming being somewhere in between or shared. And with that distinction in mind, *look* seems a better match to the advertisement’s intent.

> Attitude should be professional; look need not be.

Note that even with singular *look,* the modal expression *need not* does not become *needs not*—it is subjunctive, not indicative, and as noted and shown it governs a bare infinitive, not the kind with *to.*

Answer (score 2):

Attitude should always be professional.  Looks need not be.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is not grammatical. There are several ways to rephrase it. For example, you can say:

1- Attitude should be professional, while looks do not need to.

2- Attitude should be professional, but looks do not need to.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this sentence.

1. It has two clauses; they need to be separated, probably with a
   comma.
2. The phrase "looks need not to be" is not idiomatic, and is most
   naturally interpreted as meaning that it is *mandatory* that looks be
   unprofessional, which is unlikely.  Without the "to" it will read closer to what I assume is your intended meaning.
3. The term "looks" typically refers to a person's natural beauty or lack thereof, something that cannot easily be changed.  You probably
   mean "attire," meaning clothing and accessories.

With all those changes, one possible rendition is:

> Attitude should be professional, attire need not be.

However, I would personally go with:

> Attitude should be professional, attire can be casual.

It's not quite as catchy, but it's easier to understand.